# Cannot access PUT request body params

Tags: php, rest, yii2, postman, put

I am making this PUT request via Postman that has form-data body:
[PUT request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iYuc.png)

And trying to populate the model using this line:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams(), '');
```

[Trying to print body params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvRuF.png)

See, I tried to print worker_id, time_out params of the request on debug console, but getting null. And getBodyParams() is only returning an array of one ("image") element

[Getting all params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aozj.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For methods other than `POST` Yii2 doesn't use `$_POST` array to get body params. It uses `mb_parse_str()` on raw body [instead](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/b0aa6ab852613e71b6b707dbf997ccae20bb39a5/framework/web/Request.php#L603). This approach probably have problem parsing multipart request body.

To make yii2 parse multipart body properly you have to add [`yii\web\MultipartFormDataParser`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-multipartformdataparser) to [`yii\web\Request::$parsers`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$parsers-detail) for `multipart/form-data` content type.

You can add it in your config like this:

```php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'multipart/form-data' => 'yii\web\MultipartFormDataParser'
            ],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```